# Google Maps API v3 - Zooming in while maintaining location of clicked location or marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I want to zoom in on a marker when I click it without altering its position relative to the bounds of my current map view.

[Zoomed Out Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oia0E.png)

[Zoomed In Image with marker location relative to border unchanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QgpV.png)

Does anyone know how this could could work? The following does not preserve the marker location.

```
newMarker.addListener('click', function() {
    closeAllInfoWindows();
    var pos = newMarker.position();
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    map.panTo(pos);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample from the [Simple Click listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple).
It zooms while maintaining the position of the marker. Just fill in your lat and long values.

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

  map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
    // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
    // marker.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    }, 3000);
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
```

Comment: this works if you want the marker to remain in the center. I would like to hover my mouse over a marker in, for example, the top left, and have the map zoom while allowing me to continue zooming towards the marker without moving my mouse. (see the functionality of scrolling to zoom in on the web version of google maps). Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you to read [Maps Event Listeners](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events). Give it a try. Immerse yourself. :)